iFFT a Known Transformed Function to Get the Unknown Complex-valued Initial Function
Background:
In my case, I need to get the solution of a series of 2D equations. The analytical expression of this solution ($f$) is not available but the transformed one is. Therefore, I need to inverse transform the transformed solution ($F$) using iFFT.
Description:
For a real-valued initial 1D function ($f$), its transformed result ($F$) is conjugated due to the format of FFT
$$
\Re(F(2)) = \Re(F(\mathrm{N_{fft}})),\\
 \Im(F(2)) = -\Im(F(\mathrm{N_{fft}}))).
$$
So, the numerical inverse goes well.
However, regarding the complex-valued situation ($f = a + bi$), like Green's functions, it seems that the transformed discrete function values ($F$) have no clear characteristics along the middle,  the second half of values
$$
 \underbrace{\Re(A(\mathrm{N_{fft}}))+\Im(B(\mathrm{N_{fft}}))} + \underbrace{(-\Im(A(\mathrm{N_{fft}}))+\Re(B(\mathrm{N_{fft}})))}i  \\
C_1\quad \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad D_1
$$
cannot be constructed from the first half
$$
 \underbrace{\Re(A(2))-\Im(B(2))} + \underbrace{(\Im(A(2))+\Re(B(2)))}i . \\
C_2\quad \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad D_2
$$
No conjugations or other helpful properties between $C_1/C_2$ and $D_1/D_2$ could be found.
Question:
What should I do to iFFT the known transformed results of a unknown complex-valued function to get it? By the way, if this complex-valued function is symmetric, the its FFT also has this property and could be inversely numerically transformed. But what about the general cases?
